# Updating innerHTML property of a tag in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to update `innerHTML` property of paragraph tag in PHP. I made a rest API call that gets the date and after parsing it. I am adding the result(HTML table constructed by parsing the results from API) to a `<P>` tag already in page. I am using following PHP code to do so:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$child = $dom->createElement('p',$myresult);
$dom->appendChild($child);
$dom->SaveHTML();
```

`$myresult` is the string that contain html table with information. The above lines are executed smoothly but no change in `p` tag content.

I tried this too, but no change in output:

```
<?php echo "<script>document.getElementByID("#id").innerHTML = ". $myresult."</script>"
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: why not directly use `$myresult` in html tag, like `<div id="id"><?php echo $myresult; ?></div>` ?

Comment: Are you actually putting an # in front of the id value in getElementByID?

Comment: @Matz nope. just for question formatting i used #.

Comment: @Jigar I did that too, but no change in p content

Comment: Not sure what is in $myresult but you will probably need single quotes around the $myresult value as you are echoing the script

Comment: @Matz i tried that too. the statement is executed with our any error, but not getting reflected in web page. and $myresult is a string which contain html table. I echoed and checked the content of $myresult. its as expected

Comment: @Manikanta then `var_dump($myresult)` to find its value, don't do it via JS. Just a suggestion, upto you though. After page is loaded, inpect element in browser to check if that html is present.

Comment: Perhaps edit the post and add a more complete set of the code for us to better test

Comment: @Jigar var_dump($myresult) prints the content on first line of page. but I want to add the result to a particular section in web page.

Comment: `var_dump` is used for debugging generally, to check the value in variable. Yes, update your question with more code so ppl can help.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<?php echo "<script>document.getElementById(\"id\").innerHTML=".$myresult."</script>" ?>
```

as long as `id` is an existing html element id and `$myresult` is a php variable containing html

OR

You may try

```
<div id="id"><?php echo $myresult; ?></div>
```

Notes:
1. It is `getElementById()` not `getElementByID()`
2. Usually `#id` is used in jquery, and in pure JS it is just `id`

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. I tried both, no change in p tag content. and the syntax if getID and #id are just for formatting question I typed. I am using IDE so no issues of syntax.

Comment: are you parsing your rest API in php or JS?

Comment: in PHP and constructing the $myresult variable in PHP

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php echo "<script>document.getElementByID(\"id\").innerHTML = ". $myresult."</script>" ?>
```

you need escaping quotation on getElementByID and u dont need `#`

Answer (score -1):

You should **escape** double quotes inside a double-quote string in PHP. But, you can as well use single quotes instead like so:

```
<?php echo "<script> document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = '$myresult' </script>"; ?>
```

Also, it is `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. And remove the **#** from `getElementById()`.